# Delayed evaluation in Scheme

Tags: if-statement, scheme, evaluation, short-circuiting, delayed-execution

Given the following code:

```
(define (my-if condition iftrue iffalse) 
 (cond (condition iftrue) 
         (else iffalse)))

'-----example1
(my-if #t 
        (display "my if was true!")  
        (display "my if was false!")) 
(newline)
'-----example2
(my-if #t
        (display "my if was true!")
        (+ 2 3))
```

why would example 1 evaluate both parameters right away giving an output of

```
my if was true!my if was false!
```

yet in example 2 only

```
my if was true!
```

is the output?

Is this because `display` is never delayed but arithmetic operators are, or is it something else?

Answer (score 3):

In *both* cases *both* arguments get evaluated - that's how *procedures* work, all the arguments to a function call are evaluated *before* the function body is executed, they are *never* delayed! (unless explicitly done so).

And that's why you can't implement `my-if` as a procedure, it *has to* be a special form, like `if` and `cond`, which only evaluate the part corresponding to a true condition, or the `else` part if none is true. Also, bear in mind that `display` just *prints* its argument on the console, but it doesn't *return* any value.

Your second example prints the message, but the addition too got executed anyway, it's just that its value wasn't returned because the *first* condition was true, so `my-if` returns the value of its first parameter, which is a value returned from the `display` call (*before* `my-if` is entered), which is void. For instance, see what this outputs on the console:

```
(my-if #t
       (+ 2 3)
       (display "my if was false!"))
```

As expected, both parameters get evaluated, but only the first one's value is returned:

```
my if was false! ; this got printed anyway
5                ; this is the value returned by `my-if`
```

Comment: You meant `(display "my if was false!")` for the else case, right?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can use [lazy racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/), but if so, this will work for you

```
#lang lazy

(define (my-if p t f)
  (cond [p t]
        [else f]))

(my-if #t (display 'true) (display 'false))

; => true
```

If you run it in normal racket ...

```
#lang racket

(define (if p t f)
  (cond [p t]
        [else f]))

(if #t (display 'true) (display 'false))

; => truefalse
```

---

Another way you could achieve laziness would be wrapping the arguments in lambdas:

```
#lang racket

(define (my-if p t f)
  ; this calls the correct function with zero arguments
  ((if p t f)))

; wrap the delayed arguments in zero-argument functions
(my-if #t (λ () (display 'true)) (λ () (display 'false)))

; => true
```

Comment: The last one isn't a very good use of `eval`, especially when you can do `(define-syntax my-if  (syntax-rules () ((my-if p c a) (cond (p c) (else a)))))`

Comment: How about instead of using `quote` and `eval`, using thunks to delay the arguments?